# WP7 Sterling very slow storing lots of data

Tags: windows-phone-7, sterling-db

I'm trying to store 46,000 objects in Sterling and it's taking 3 minutes.

Yes I know it's a lot but this is data provided by the customer and could end up being a lot more.

I'm guessing each time I save a new object it is looking up the key to see if the object has already been stored.

Is there any way to bypass this and tell sterling to just insert?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your data structure it's a bit difficult to recommend ways in which you could improve performance, however:

- The fewer indexes you create for your data tables the fewer indexes there are to create when your data is persisted. You should look carefully at which indexes you need for your data read scenarios.
- The more data relationships there are, the more metadata there is to create at write time. You may be able to simplify the data structures and combine classes.
- Sheer volume of data sounds like your biggest problem. I've experienced similar problems before with trying to persist large volumes of GPS data. The problem there is that I was trying to write a lot of relatively small amounts of data related to a single piece of data in another table. I managed to resolve this by consolidating the GPS data into a single string and persisting it as a field with the main record. This offloaded a **lot** of the read/write time into a significantly smaller amount of time for rehydrating the data when it was actually needed.

I woudl definitely recommend reachign out to Jeremy and the Sterling team via the [CodePlex site](http://sterling.codeplex.com) if none of the above help.

Comment: It's a fairly simple class with 5 fields. The key is a guid. I have one compound index using 2 ints. No relationships. You are correct about the volume of data being the problem. I previously handles this myself into the iso store and it took around 35 seconds. I thought Sterling may speed things up but it's now up to 4 mins! I only Flush after all the records have been saved so it looks like the majority of the time is checking/updating keys and indexes in memory.

Comment: If you can write the data yourself in about 35 seconds, what does Sterling give you that handling it yourself doesn't? It definitely sounds like a scenario worth reaching out to Jeremy for.

Comment: I have posted a message on the Sterling forum. My problem is that storing it in one large file makes updating a slow process. I was hoping Sterling would be faster than my efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered keeping most data server-side, and presenting client with only a window into that data, something like 20 or 50 rows at a time?

EDIT: since the answer in no, I'd turn off the database table index while the operation is going, or use SQL bulk copy.

Comment: Unfortunately we need to run the app in offline mode so the data needs to be downloaded and stored locally.